How to find the Proportion?
How to find the Proportion?
Clear["`*"]
a = 2 k; b = 3 k; c = 4 k; k > 0;
(a + b) : (b + c) : (c + a)

How can I get this result?
(a + b) : (b + c) : (c + a) == 5 : 7 : 6


I know that English is not your native language, but please make sure to find the correct English terms when posting a question, not those that come out of online translators. Conjunction is something completely different, I assume you mean proportions.

I'm just confused, how can you make such a translation mistake?: https://i.sstatic.net/xVFtodMi.png What Chinese phrase are you using? In any case, I don't see your effort (-1).

a = 2 k; b = 3 k; c = 4 k;

f = {a + b, b + c, c + a}
(*    {5 k, 7 k, 6 k}    *)

f / (PolynomialGCD @@ f)
(*    {5, 7, 6}    *)

The same thing but expressed in a cleaner way:
Normalize[f, Apply[PolynomialGCD]]
(*    {5, 7, 6}    *)


There is also Proportion[5, 7, 6] but just for formatting purposes.
